# How to mock a function calling io.Copy

Tags: go

Trying to mock the following function. It basically takes an object from S3 (`io.ReadCloser`) and writes it to a file that execution `os.Open()`d earlier (`io.WriteCloser`).

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func writeFile(destination io.WriteCloser, source io.ReadCloser) error {
    defer destination.Close()
    defer source.Close()
    _, err := io.Copy(destination, source)
    if err != nil {
        log.WithFields(log.Fields{"desc": "unable to copy contents from s3 to blahblah"}).Error(err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I think I'm pretty close, but at the moment my test hangs and never errors / succeeds... I also realized that I can pass `os.Stdout` to my destination, but still ran into the same issue. Something is going on within `io.Copy`. I imagine it's because I'm trying to copy empty data to nothing?

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "io"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type mockReadCloser struct {}

func (m mockReadCloser) Read(p []byte) (int, error) { return 0, nil }
func (m mockReadCloser) Close() error               { return nil }

type mockWriteCloser struct{}

func (m mockWriteCloser) Close() error                      { return nil }
func (m mockWriteCloser) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) { return 0, nil }

func Test_writeFile(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        destination io.WriteCloser
        source      io.ReadCloser
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {
            name: "",
            args: args{
                destination: &mockWriteCloser{},
                source:      &mockReadCloser{},
            },
            wantErr: false,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if err := writeFile(tt.args.destination, tt.args.source); (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("writeFile() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because [io.Copy](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy) doesn't return until EOF or error.

> Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs. It returns the number of bytes copied and the first error encountered while copying, if any.
>
> A successful Copy returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because Copy is defined to read from src until EOF, it does not treat an EOF from Read as an error to be reported.

So, if you return EOF from your `mockReadCloser.Read`, it shouldn't hang any more.

```golang
func (m mockReadCloser) Read(p []byte) (int, error) { return 0, io.EOF }
```

This is because Read is called repeatedly until there is nothing more to read (EOF).

```golang
for {
    nr, er := src.Read(buf)
    ...
}
```